# pandas merge dataframes: keep all rows when one of the columns matches another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I would want to find a way in python to merge the files on 'seq' but return all the ones with the same id, in this example only the lines with id 2 would be removed.

File one:

```
seq,id
CSVGPPNNEQFF,0
CTVGPPNNEQFF,0
CTVGPPNNERFF,0
CASRGEAAGFYEQYF,1
RASRGEAAGFYEQYF,1
CASRGGAAGFYEQYF,1
CASSDLILYYEQYF,2
CASSDLILYYTQYF,2
CASSGSYEQYF,3
CASSGSYEQYY,3
```

File two:

```
seq
CSVGPPNNEQFF
CASRGEAAGFYEQYF
CASSGSYEQYY
```

Output:

```
seq,id
CSVGPPNNEQFF,0
CTVGPPNNEQFF,0
CTVGPPNNERFF,0
CASRGEAAGFYEQYF,1
RASRGEAAGFYEQYF,1
CASRGGAAGFYEQYF,1
CASSGSYEQYF,3
CASSGSYEQYY,3
```

I have tried:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.groupby('seq',as_index=False)[['seq']].agg(','.join),how='right')
```

output:

```
seq,id
CASRGEAAGFYEQYF,1
CASSGSYEQYY,3
CSVGPPNNEQFF,0
```

Does anyone have any advice how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to *merge* two dataframes, or just take subset of the first dataframe according to which `id` is included in the second dataframe (by `seq`)? Anyway, this gives the required result.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'seq': [
        'CSVGPPNNEQFF',
        'CTVGPPNNEQFF',
        'CTVGPPNNERFF',
        'CASRGEAAGFYEQYF',
        'RASRGEAAGFYEQYF',
        'CASRGGAAGFYEQYF',
        'CASSDLILYYEQYF',
        'CASSDLILYYTQYF',
        'CASSGSYEQYF',
        'CASSGSYEQYY'
    ],
    'id': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'seq': [
        'CSVGPPNNEQFF',
        'CASRGEAAGFYEQYF',
        'CASSGSYEQYY'
    ]
})

df3 = df1.loc[df1['id'].isin(df1['id'][df1['seq'].isin(df2['seq'])])]
```

Explanation: `df1['id'][df1['seq'].isin(df2['seq'])]` takes those values of `id` from `df1` that contain at least one `seq` that is included in `df2`. Then all rows with those values of `id` are taken from `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the isin() pandas method, code shall looks as follow :

```
df1.loc[df1['seq'].isin(df2['seq'])]
```

Assuming, both objects are pandas dataframe and 'seq' is a column.

Comment: The output of this command is exactly like what I had with the df.merge command.

Comment: My bad, I didn't get the point about 'id' in your question. The other answer given is the right one.